# ipython notebook - uploading from and saving to subdirectories?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

[Change IPython working directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680463/change-ipython-working-directory)
[Inserting image into IPython notebook markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628262/inserting-image-into-ipython-notebook-markdown)

Hi, I've read the two above links, and the second link seems most relevant. what the person describes - simply calling the subdirectory - doesn't work for me. For instance, I have an image 'gephi.png' in '/Graphs/gephi.png'
But when I write the following

```
from IPython.display import Image
path = "/Graphs/gephi.png"
i = Image(path)
i
```

no image pops up - Yup. No error. Just nothing pops up besides an empty square box image.

Clarification: 
When I move the image to the regular director, the image pops up fine. 
My only code change is path = "gephi.png"

Comment: Have you executed the line? If there is an error, you should see an error message...

Comment: Yup. No error. Just nothing pops up besides an empty square box image.

Comment: Maybe that are the contents of the image? Anyway, why didn't you include this in the question? We didn't see this pop up, you know...

Comment: Note that also ipython may automatically scale down the image for display. So if this is a huge graph, the scaling may end up keeping all the white inbetween of your nodes only.

Comment: Looking at the path to image in description & code, aren't you missing a "/" before Graphs in the code?

Comment: @Amit, sorry that was a typo - i did have the forward slash in the original code, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @anony-Mousse It works if you just have the path in the main file folder. the image comes up in the notebook.

Comment: Are you sure the path is fully correct, and your OSX isn't playing tricks on you, by presenting you fake paths in finder or something like this? In a terminal, does `ls -l /Graphs/gephi.png` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPython's Image display object takes three kinds of arguments

The first is raw image data (e.g. the results of `open(filename).read()`:

```
with open("Graphs/graph.png") as f:
    data = f.read()
Image(data=data)
```

The second model is to load an image from a filename. This is functionally the same as above, but IPython does the reading from the file:

```
Image(filename="Graphs/graph.png")
```

The third form is passing URLs. External URLs can be used, but relative URIs will serve files relative to the notebook's own directory:

```
Image(url="Graphs/graph.png")
```

Where this can get confusing is if you don't tell IPython which one of these you are specifying, and you just pass the one argument positionally:

```
Image("Graphs/graph.png")
```

IPython tries to guess what you mean in this case:

1. if it looks like a path *and* points to an existing file, use it as a filename
2. if it looks like a URL, use it as a URL
3. otherwise, fallback on embedding the string as raw png data

That #3 is the source of the most confusion. If you pass it a filename that doesn't exist,
you will get a broken image:

```
Image("/Graphs/graph.png")
```

Note that URLs to local files must be relative. Absolute URLs will generally be wrong:

```
Image(url="/Graphs/graph.png")
```

[An example notebook](http://minrk.github.io/junk/nb/image_arguments.html) illustrating these things.

Comment: Thanks for this. The Raw image data option works! Conversely, if I wanted to save to a subdirectory, is there a similar way to do that?

Comment: It is in a subdirectory in all of these cases - `Graphs` is a directory adjacent to the notebook file. If you want it more deeply nested, just use `any/other/subdir/graph.png`