# How to upload image in iPython Notebook in Markdown environment?

Tags: image, upload, ipython, markdown

I've looked at several posts, [including this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628262/inserting-image-into-ipython-notebook-markdown), but I can't seem to get it to work. I've done as what one user commented under the chosen answer. Here's what I literally typed in the Markdown cell in iPython:

```
[blahblah](/Users/MyName/Python/testfile.png)
```

But it doesn't work. I also tried putting qutation marks around the file path and it doesn't work either. I'm *certain* that that is the correct path.

How can I upload an image? What should I literally type?

Answer (score 0):

Image links in Markdown begin with a `!`, see https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#img. What you typed is only a link. Try this:

```
![blahblah](/Users/MyName/Python/testfile.png)
```

In case of spaces in your image path, escape them with `\`:

```
![blahblah](/Users/My\ Name/Python\ iNotebook/testfile.png)
```