# Image in Markdown cell Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown

Looking for examples on how to post an image in a `Markdown` cell in a `Jupyter Notebook`, I came acrross this code which should work:

```
![title](/home/my/path/to/image/image.jpg)
```

However, when clicking enter to execute the command the output does not contain the image. Am I missing something? I am working on a Linux (ubuntu) machine and using `jupyter` from an `anaconda env`

[image]

Comment: Does it work with a web url ?

Comment: @RMPR Did not try as the image I want to use is in my local disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For others looking into the same issue:

Just found out that by drag and dropping the image in the `Markdown` cell, it works perfectlly. Credits to @Rich Lysakowski PhD in this post - [Inserting image into IPython notebook markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628262/inserting-image-into-ipython-notebook-markdown)