# How to include an image in a Jupyter Lab notebook

Tags: python, data-science, jupyter-lab

In Jupyter Notebook I can use the following:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

file = open("./image.png", "rb")
image = file.read()
widgets.Image(
    value=image,
    format='png',
    width=700,
    height=100,
)
```

This doesn't work in Jupyter Lab though, what is the Jupyter Lab version of the above?

Comment: The simplest way is this (without writing code is): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628262/inserting-image-into-ipython-notebook-markdown/55623116#55623116

Comment: This question has already been answered at [Inserting image into IPython notebook markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628262/inserting-image-into-ipython-notebook-markdown/55623116#55623116)

Comment: @RichLysakowskiPhD "drag and drop" is not an answer to the question asked in this post, it's referencing a specific code snippet which worked in notebook.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple solution would be, via Markdown :-)

you can do it directly in a markdown cell:

```
![title](./image.png)
```

or via a python cell:

```
from IPython.display import HTML, display, Markdown, Latex
display(Markdown("![title](./image.png)")
```

or via a markdown cell:

```
<img src="./image.png" style="height: 300px;"/>
```

Or via a python cell:

```
display(Markdown('<img src="image.png" style="height: 300px;"/>'))
```