# How to insert an image into a Jupyter-lab notebook with iRuby kernel

Tags: jupyter-lab, iruby

I am using iruby kernel in Jupyter-lab. I wish to insert an image systematically from Ruby code into the notebook, as a result of some calculations. Typically the image will be a *.png.

The same question is answerred  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61305845/how-to-include-an-image-in-a-jupyter-lab-notebook), but for Python. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fond a solution that for me is acceptable

```
IRuby.html('<img src="./simple1.png">')
```