# Can't Insert an image in Jupyter Notebook 7 update

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub, jupyter-console

Back in earlier versions of Jupyter Notebook, steps on inserting image were:

1. change cell to **markdown**
2. click on **edit**
3. select **insert** **image**

Is there any way of doing it in *Jupyter Notebook 7* as the option of insert image is not present in the edit tab.
[edit tab in Jupyter Notebook 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgNQy.png)

Comment: Jupyter Notebook 7+ is built on the same components as JupyterLab and so the approaches established there are the ones to follow in modern Jupyter. I'll have to find the reference later to the StackOverflow post where it tells how you drag and drop the images into markdown to embed. More soon.

Comment: [This excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55623116/8508004) describes the best ways to do this. I don't see it quite updated for Jupyter 7+ yet and so maybe we can discuss here if that is working for you?